# mdframed - how to make the box larger to fit my table?

Tags: arrays, mdframed

My code is given below. How can I make the box bigger so that the table fits inside it? Or how could I make the table smaller so that it fits inside the box?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}
 \usepackage{thmtools}
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

 \theoremstyle{definition}
  \mdfdefinestyle{mdbluebox}{%
roundcorner = 10pt,
linewidth=1pt,
skipabove=10pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
innerbottommargin=9pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
nobreak=true,
linecolor=blue,
backgroundcolor=TealBlue!5,
}
 \declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{MidnightBlue},
mdframed={style=mdbluebox},
headpunct={\\[3pt]},
postheadspace={0pt}
]{thmbluebox}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdredbox}{%
roundcorner = 10pt,
linewidth=1pt,
skipabove=10pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
innerbottommargin=9pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
nobreak=true,
linecolor=RubineRed,
backgroundcolor=red!2,
}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries\color{RubineRed},
mdframed={style=mdredbox},
headpunct={\\[3pt]},
postheadspace={0pt},
]{thmredbox}

\declaretheorem[%
style=thmbluebox,name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox,name=Example,sibling=theorem]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
 $\small
  \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
  \text{Mass, $m$ kg} & 2<m\leq 4  & 4<m\leq 5 & 5<m\leq 5.5 & 5.5<m\leq 6 & 
  6<m\leq 8 & 8<m\leq 10 \\ \hline
  \text{Frequency} & 12 & 13 & 31 & 34 & 10 & 8 \\ \hline
  \end{array}$
 \end{example}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you use open/closed interval notation?
[image: output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}
 \usepackage{thmtools}
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

 \theoremstyle{definition}
  \mdfdefinestyle{mdbluebox}{%
roundcorner = 10pt,
linewidth=1pt,
skipabove=10pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
innerbottommargin=9pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
nobreak=true,
linecolor=blue,
backgroundcolor=TealBlue!5,
}
 \declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{MidnightBlue},
mdframed={style=mdbluebox},
headpunct={\\[3pt]},
postheadspace={0pt}
]{thmbluebox}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdredbox}{%
roundcorner = 10pt,
linewidth=1pt,
skipabove=10pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
innerbottommargin=9pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
nobreak=true,
linecolor=RubineRed,
backgroundcolor=red!2,
}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries\color{RubineRed},
mdframed={style=mdredbox},
headpunct={\\[3pt]},
postheadspace={0pt},
]{thmredbox}

\declaretheorem[%
style=thmbluebox,name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox,name=Example,sibling=theorem]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
 $\small
  \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
   \text{Mass, $m$ kg} & (2, 4]  & (4, 5] & (5, 5.5] & (5.5, 6] & (6, 8] & (8, 10] \\ \hline
   \text{Frequency} & 12 & 13 & 31 & 34 & 10 & 8 \\ \hline
  \end{array}$
 \end{example}
\end{document}
```